# Does performing turbo boosts as soon as the bar fills give more of a boost?

Tags: crash-team-racing

In Crash Team Racing, you can get up to 3 turbo boosts by power-sliding. There is a power-meter that, when it turns red (about halfway on the meter) means you're ready to perform a boost.

The bar on the bottom right, filling up:
[image: Crash Bandicoot screaming around a corner, the boost bar in the bottom right, filling up]

Ready to boost!

[image: Crash, again screaming around a corner. This time, the bar along the right is full, ready to boost]

However if the power meter fills out, you'll backfire and be unable to boost.

Long story short, There's a specific timeframe when you can boost, on one side, your power bar is too low, on the other, too high. However the sweet-spot is long enough that you can control when you want to hit the boost, which is useful for timing boosts when you're screaming around corners etc.

What I want to know is, **should I be aiming to hit the boost as soon as the bar turns red, or should I wait and hold off until it's closer to the end?**

Does holding off give more 'boost' time?

Comment: +1 because this is the only question about Crash Team Racing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the current answer is wrong.

If you wait longer you will have a turbo that last longer (not stronger). The more you do them the longer it will stay once you stop doing any.

You can just try it in an arena, do a 3 times very short turbo twice and go in straight line without doing anything. Repeat with doing longer, it will last longer.

This is extremelly usefull to know because the more those "invisble stack" you have, the longer also the boost given by the arrow will last. Which means you can actually be on most of the circuit at max speed once you stepped in one arrow, no need for a mask.

Source : my own discovery but also available on this guide http://ctrgamers.forumotion.com/t1122-professional-guide-of-crash-team-racing . It's called sacred fire.

Comment: This answer is worded slightly unclear, but is actually correct. For reference you might want to have a look at this speedrunning guide which also explains additional techniques (it's a fast video): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6C9dA3hcL70 For further reference you might want to check out the current world record of the story mode where "late boosting" is used to its full effect. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-G4SRmo0RE

Comment: My english is quite rough, if you wanna edit you're welcome. I used  ctrgamer because when I was trying hard I found that forum back then with all that I have found myself and some more (I think it was atleast 6 years back or even more, does make me feel a bit old: '( )

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the boost is at its maximum potential the moment the power bar turns red. And even if there does happen to be a slight increase in speed, it isn't significant enough to risk the many (of which some will be inevitable) backfiring boosts.

Comment: do you have any source for this? (Just wondering)

Comment: I don't have any official sources for this, but everybody on the internet I can find has come to the same conclusion.

Comment: -1 because out of my experience this is incorrect. See comment under Walfrat's answer for references.